# What does this line in The Flash Season 4 Episode 18 mean?

Tags: dialogue, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash* S04E18, when the Thinker is cuffed by Ralph Dibny using metahuman dampener cuffs, he says:

> Before you cuff a meta, make sure the light is the right color.

He was able to break free from the cuffs after saying this. Also, he had the power of all the metas except Dibny at that point so did he use some metas ability to uncuff himself. What color is DeVoe referring to here? What is the context of this line here?

Basically, I want to ask that what exactly he did to free himself.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Killgore's power as everything that is electronic turns purple when it is under his control

Comment: DeVoe 'kilgored' the cuffs _before_ they were put on him (he couldn't have done it when the cuffs were on, because that's the whole point of the cuffs), but Dibny failed to notice the color change to purple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by light he meant purple light because there was purple color on the cuffs which appears while using Kilgore's power.